# css explained for selecting the aplicable element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can somebody please explain what the selectors mean?
As far as I understand having #myId - is css for control with id=myId.
.myClass is Css for controls with class myClass.
Can somebody please explain the other combinations?

```
div.img a:hover img
  {
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
  }
div.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:120px;
  margin:2px;
  }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference#Selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id (#) can exist only once in a document. It is really useful to identify an element in CSS ans in JavaScript as well (should you ever need it).`

A class (.) can be used as often as it is required.

Example: you have only one header: `<div id="header">Header</div>`, but several articles: `<div class="article">...</div>`

---

Say you have this HTML document:

```
<div id="site">
    <h1>Some heading...</h1>
    <div class="article">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Some content...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Some content...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The heading of the articles shouldn't be as big as the heading of the site, so we have to use a more specific selector: `.article h1 {...}`. This will style every `<h1>`element in a element of the class "article".

If we want to have an even more specific selector, we would use: `div.article h1 {...}`. This will only style every `<h1>` element in a `<div>` box with the class "article"

Answer (score 1):

`div.img a:hover img`

selects images that are inside hovered links, that are inside `div` elements with class `img`, and gives them a blue border.

`div.desc`

selects `div`s with the class `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

`div.img a:hover img` means: find me an `img` element which is a descendant of an `a` element that is currently being hovered over, which is in turn a descendant of a `div` element with a class name og `img`.

`div.desc` simply selects any `div` with a class name of `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the standards definition, I always find this useful: [CSS selectors at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Answer (score 0):

```
div.img a:hover img
```

This will match any `img` tag that is within an `a` tag which is currently in a `hover` state that is within a `div` tag that has `class="img"`.

```
div.desc
```

This will match any `div` tag with `class="desc"`.

When items are chained like this with only spaces between them, it matches on that specific hierarchy of elements.  For example, in the first one, an `img` tag that's not in an `a` tag won't be matched.

You can also delimit items with a comma, which instead of matching a hierarchy of items will match each item individually.  So something like `div.img, img` will match any `div` tag with `class="img"` and will match any `img` tag.

Specifically for the `:hover` attribute, that's called a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors).  It modifies the attribute to which it's attached (in this case an `a`) by looking for items of that type which are in a specific state (in this case, being hovered over).